# Using map.reduce on one column from a 2d array

Tags: google-apps-script, reduce

Ok so I just want to know the numbers x's in a given column of my data. I know I can do it with this:

```
function countx (data,column){
var result = 0;
for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
    {
    if(data[i][column]=="x") result++;    
    }  
return result;
}
```

But it seems like this would be much better done with a map.reduce, but I'm not sure how to use reduce on a 2d array and I found the most popular thread on here about this topic much more complex than my situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to convert the following script to the script using map and reduce.

  ```
  function countx (data,column){
  var result = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
      {
      if(data[i][column]=="x") result++;    
      }  
  return result;
  }
  ```

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modified script:

```
function countx (data,column) {
  var result = data.reduce(function(c, e) {
    if (e[column] == "x") c++;
    return c;
  }, 0);
  return result;
}
```

- In your script, I think that "reduce" is suitable instead of "map".
- When "reduce" is used, the initial value can be given as `}, 0);`.
- In this modified script, it can be run with and without enabling V8.

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method would be [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
function countx (data,column){
  return data.filter(row=>row[column]==="x").length;
}
console.info(countx([["a"],["b"],["x"],["x"],["c"]],0))
```